# R: How do I define function argument default as NULL when argument is factor

Tags: r, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass arguments to a function which are factor data types, while defining default value as NULL.  A simplified example is below:

```
my_function <-  function(my_arg = c(NULL,"this","that")){
    Do stuff here...
}
```

This does not seem to work, as if I define the function as follows:

```
my_function <-  function(my_arg = c(NULL,"this","that")){
    print(my_arg)
}
```

the result is :

```
> my_function()
```

[1] "this" "that"

Not sure how to have a parameter passed as a factor which has a defined default value of NULL.  Thanks!

EDIT:

Thank you for your responses, but these do not really answer my question.  Perhaps I was not specific enough.  My example is a highly simplified example of what I am actually trying to accomplish, but what I need is to specify an argument that can take on one of three values -- "this", "that", and NULL.  Further to this, I need to set the default value to NULL.  I can simply set my_arg = NULL, but then I have not specified in the function signature that my arg must be one of these three options.  Your solutions do neither of these for me.  If I pass as a list, say

```
my_function <-  function(my_arg = list(NULL,"this","that")){
  print(my_arg)
}
```

This results in the following:

```
> my_function("this")
[1] "this"
> my_function("asdf")
[1] "asdf"
> my_function()
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "this"

[[3]]
[1] "that"
```

So if I do not pass a value to my_args specifically, it will iterate through the function using each value listed in the signature.  What I need is for the function to accept either NULL, "this", or "that" as values for the argument, while setting NULL as the default if nothing is passed.

Answer (score 1):

A vector can't contain `NULL`. You need a list for this:

```
c(NULL,"this","that")
#[1] "this" "that"
list(NULL,"this","that")
#[[1]]
#NULL
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "this"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "that"
```

As the documentation says:

> NULL represents the null object in R

And the Language Definition explains further:

> 2.1.6 NULL
>
> There is a special object called NULL. It is used whenever there is a
>   need to indicate or specify that an object is absent. It should not be
>   confused with a vector or list of zero length.
>
> The NULL object has no type and no modifiable properties. There is
>   only one NULL object in R, to which all instances refer. To test for
>   NULL use is.null. You cannot set attributes on NULL.

A vector can only contain values of one type and since `NULL` has no type it can't be in a vector. Assigning `NULL` to a subset with `<-` removes the subset and `c` will just ignore `NULL`.

Comment: Please see me added comments above.  This does not really answer my question, so I elaborated above.  Your solution does not set a default value for argument, if none is specifically passed

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you expect to happen if an argument other than "this" or "that" is passed to the function? You don't seem to have understood how function arguments are handled in R.

Comment: Yes, I think I get this.  In order to restrict the values passed into my_arg, I need to simply put code into my function that actually throws an error if one of these values is not passed.  I get this now, so thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the arguments individually:

```
my_function <-  function(my_arg1 = NULL, my_arg2="this", my_arg3="that"){
    print(is.null(my_arg1))
} 
#> my_function()
#[1] TRUE
```

Or, as pointed out by @Roland, you can pass them as a list:

```
my_function <-  function(my_arg = list(NULL,"this","that")){
     print(is.null(my_arg[[1]]))
} 
#> my_function()
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Please note that I added more to my original question.  I am looking to set default value to my_arg argument to NULL, while specifying that the only acceptable values for my_args (if not NULL by default) are "this" and "that".

Comment: You could use `if` statements inside your function to check whether the argument is "this" or "that", and set it to `NULL`otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing.  Thanks!!